# PHP Form Validation red error not showing around box

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm a bit new to php and I was going over a tutorial where they are making validation form, but when I try and replicate what they do I don't get the same as them, when they run the code, the input box shows up red because the user hasn't placed anything in the input box. When I try it, nothing happens, the input box doesn't show me any errors.

But when I try and submit my form with data it just sends me to the next page, and if I dont type anything I just stay in the same page.

All this code is inside index.php

```
    if(($_POST['email']) != "")
    {
        header('Location:final.php');
    }
    else{
        $emailError = "validation";
    }
```

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" >

<!--Get warning here when no input is placed-->
<div class="<?=$emailError?>">
   <label>E-mail Address:</label>
   <input type="text" name="email">
</div>
```

Comment: The red border is done with CSS

Comment: add `required` -  `<input type="text" name="email" required>`

Comment: Yes I needed CSS, the tutorial never mentioned anything about CSS but on their files that have the code, the code has css with the class validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The red border is the following code:

```
.validation {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

You can include it with your code like this

```
<style>
    .validation {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
</style>
<form method="post" action="index.php" >

<!--Get warning here when no input is placed-->
<div class="<?=$emailError?>">
   <label>E-mail Address:</label>
   <input type="text" name="email">
</div>
```